One question about Theorem 4 in Brezis–Merle's famous paper
I'm reading Theorem 4 of the paper "Uniform Estimates and Blow-up Analysis for Solutions of $-\Delta u = V(x) e^u$  in Two Dimensions" by Brezis and Merle, and at the beginning of the proof they say that we can assume without loss of generality that
$$u_n \geq 0 \quad\text{in} \quad \Omega. $$
I understand the part where they say that by Kato's inequality we have
$$ \Delta u_n^{-} \geq -(\Delta u_n)\chi_{[u_n \leq 0]}=V_ne^{u_n}\chi_{[u_n \leq 0]} \geq -|V_n|.\label{482351_41}\tag{41}$$
They then use \eqref{482351_41} and
$$\lVert u_n^{-} \rVert_{L^{1}}\leq C
\label{482351_39}\tag{39}$$
to conclude by "standard elliptic estimates" that $(u_n^{-})$ is bounded in $L_{\text{loc}}^{\infty}(\Omega)$. By this I presume that they are using Calderón–Zygmund inequality somehow, but in which way are they using it? How to use \eqref{482351_41} to obtain an $L^p$ bound for $\Delta u_n^{-}$? I need help in understanding how to conclude that $(u_n^{-})$ is bounded in $L_{\text{loc}}^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Are the $V_n$ (locally) uniformly bounded?

By hypothesis $V_n \geq 0$ in $\Omega$ and $\lVert V_n \rVert_{L^{p}} \leq C_1$ for some $1<p \leq \infty$.

Solve $\Delta h_n=-|V_n|$ (in a ball with Dirichlet b.c.) and you get $|h_n|{2,p} \leq C$. By Sobolev embedding ($p>n/2$) also $|h_n|\infty \leq C$. Then $u_n^--h_n$ is subharmonic and you can estimate (locally) the sup-norm with the $L^1$ norm, by the mean value inequality.
